# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) After reading from file

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, iostream, istream

I am trying to read a `.txt` file which looks something like this...

`Rhombus 118.5 112.4 69.9`

I am then trying to initialise my constructor for the `Shapes` class with the parameters or values `118.5`, `112.4`, `69.9`. However, I am getting a `Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)` error - and I know which line it is coming from in my code. I just don't know how to resolve it...

My code is below...

```
istream& inputpoints(istream &is, Shapes * & shape)
{
   string name;
   double x, y, z;
   if (is >> name) {
       if (is >> x >> y >> z) {
           *shape = Shapes(x, y, z); // Segementation fault (core dump) happening here
       }
   }
   return is;
}
```

I believe it is the line `*shape = Shapes(x, y, z)` that is causing all this problem. If I don't put the `*` before `shape`, then I get a `Shapes` can't be assigned to `Shapes*` error.

Would appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Several issues.  Primarily, you are assigning a pointer to temporary (stack) object to an out param.

For better style and readability, declare your function such that the second parameter is a pointer to a pointer to a ppShapes.

```
istream& inputpoints(istream &is, Shapes** ppShapes)
{
```

To fix the main problem, change this line:

```
*shape = Shapes(x, y, z); // Segementation fault (core dump) happening here
```

To be this:

```
*ppShapes = new Shapes(x, y, z);
```

Invoke inputpoints as follows:

```
Shapes* pShapes = NULL;

istream = inputpoints(istream, &pShapes);
```